# Suppress some cell numbers in a rowwise manner

Tags: r, function, dplyr, data-wrangling

I'm in the process of creating a function that does two things (for now, more functionality will come later):

1. Reads in a data frame and suppresses numeric values (by making them -1) that are >0 & <10. Also, only for columns that are not "rate" or "total" numeric columns.
2. After that, it checks which rows only have a -1 for ONLY ONE column, and if there is a -1 for ONLY ONE column in a row, then it assigns a random other column a -1 (again, one of the numeric columns that are NOT "rate" or "total" columns).

I'd like a tidyverse solution. I already have a base R / loop solution, but it is not very readable and maintainable so I am starting from scratch using tidyverse syntax.

Here is my reproducible example so far:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

# Create synthetic data for illustration and testing
my_data <- tibble(group = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 
                               each = 25),
                  day = rep(seq.Date(from = today() - 24, 
                                     to = today(), 
                                     by = "day"),
                            times = 4),
                  x = sample(x = 1:100, size = 100, replace = TRUE),
                  y = sample(x = 1:100, size = 100, replace = TRUE),
                  z = sample(x = 1:100, size = 100, replace = TRUE),
                  a = sample(x = 1:100, size = 100, replace = TRUE),
                  b = sample(x = 1:100, size = 100, replace = TRUE),
                  c = sample(x = 1:100, size = 100, replace = TRUE),
                  x_rate = x,
                  y_rate = y / 860 * 100000,
                  z_rate = z / 860 * 100000,
                  total = x)




# Function to squash small numbers

squash_small_numbers <- function(df) {
  
  # For all numeric columns, if the value is between 1 and 9, overwrite with -1
  # Don't do suppression in "rate" or "total" columns
  df1 <- df %>%
    mutate(across(where(is.numeric) & !contains(c("rate", "total")),
                  ~ifelse(.x > 0 & .x < 10,
                          -1,
                          .x)))
  
  
  # If only one of the numeric cells in a row is suppressed (-1), then randomly 
  # suppress another cell in the same row
  
  return(df1)
  
}

test_df <- squash_small_numbers(my_data)
```

I know the next step involves another call to `mutate()`, `across()`, and probably `rowwise()`, but not really sure how to actually do it

Answer (score 1):

This could work as a solution:

- a small helper function `rowOne` to test if exactly one row has a -1 value.
- a `nest`ing and `map`ping of relevant rows to sample exactly one column if one needs replaced - this is a little complex but keeps it in a tidyverse way (and I can't quite think of a neater way of sampling a column?)

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

# Create synthetic data for illustration and testing
my_data <- tibble(group = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 
                              each = 25),
                  day = rep(seq.Date(from = today() - 24, 
                                     to = today(), 
                                     by = "day"),
                            times = 4),
                  x = sample(x = 1:100, size = 100, replace = TRUE),
                  y = sample(x = 1:100, size = 100, replace = TRUE),
                  z = sample(x = 1:100, size = 100, replace = TRUE),
                  a = sample(x = 1:100, size = 100, replace = TRUE),
                  b = sample(x = 1:100, size = 100, replace = TRUE),
                  c = sample(x = 1:100, size = 100, replace = TRUE),
                  x_rate = x,
                  y_rate = y / 860 * 100000,
                  z_rate = z / 860 * 100000,
                  total = x)




# Function to squash small numbers

squash_small_numbers <- function(df) {
  
  # For all numeric columns, if the value is between 1 and 9, overwrite with -1
  # Don't do suppression in "rate" or "total" columns
  df1 <- df %>%
    mutate(across(where(is.numeric) & !contains(c("rate", "total")),
                  ~ifelse(.x > 0 & .x < 10,
                          -1,
                          .x)))
  
  
  # If only one of the numeric cells in a row is suppressed (-1), then randomly 
  # suppress another cell in the same row

  # Test across all rows to see if exactly one equals -1
  rowOne <- function(x) rowSums(x == -1) == 1
  
  df1 <- df1 %>%
    mutate(if_one = rowOne(across(where(is.numeric) &
                                    !contains(c(
                                      "rate", "total"
                                    ))))) %>%
    # Put relevant rows in nested dataframe to work on
    nest(data = where(is.numeric) &
           !contains(c("rate", "total"))) %>%
    mutate(data = map2(data, if_one, ~ if (.y) {
      # If needs replacement, then choose one of the relevant columns to replace
      replacement <-
        sample(
          colnames(.x)[map_lgl(colnames(.x), function(columns) .x[columns] != -1)],
          1)
      .x[replacement] <- -1
      .x
      
    } else {
      .x
    })) %>%
    unnest(data) %>% 
    select(-if_one)
  
  return(df1)
  
}

test_df <- squash_small_numbers(my_data)

test_df
#> # A tibble: 100 x 12
#>    group day        x_rate y_rate z_rate total     x     y     z     a     b
#>    <chr> <date>      <int>  <dbl>  <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 A     2021-12-13     88  7442. 11628.    88    88    64   100    87    56
#>  2 A     2021-12-14     28  5814.  6860.    28    28    50    59    -1    -1
#>  3 A     2021-12-15     19  7674.  1512.    19    19    66    13    76    96
#>  4 A     2021-12-16     97   116.  9767.    97    97    -1    84    -1    84
#>  5 A     2021-12-17     94   814.  3372.    94    -1    -1    29    73    50
#>  6 A     2021-12-18     16  8837.  4651.    16    16    76    40    83    26
#>  7 A     2021-12-19     86  8605.   116.    86    86    74    -1    46    13
#>  8 A     2021-12-20     65  1860.  6860.    65    65    16    59    47    47
#>  9 A     2021-12-21     87  9535. 10698.    87    87    82    92    59    94
#> 10 A     2021-12-22     28  7558.  9651.    28    28    65    83    92    86
#> # ... with 90 more rows, and 1 more variable: c <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for this solution! I selected it because it is the most readable and tidyverse-esque.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function that does the random assignment, assuming that the argument passed to the function is the dataframe you get after the `across(...)` call. Something like this

```
random_assign <- function(df) {
  v <- df == -1
  rs <- which(rowSums(v) == 1L)
  cs <- which(t(v[rs, ]), TRUE)[, "row"]
  other_cs <- sample.int(ncol(v) - 1L, length(cs), replace = TRUE)
  other_cs <- sapply(cs, setdiff, x = seq_len(ncol(v)))[cbind(other_cs, seq_along(cs))]
  `[<-.data.frame`(df, cbind(rs, other_cs), value = -1L)
}
```

Then apply it to the result of `across(...)` since all the columns you want to change are captured by `across`

```
my_data %>% mutate(random_assign(across(
  where(is.numeric) & !contains(c("rate", "total")), 
  ~`[<-`(.x, .x > 0L & .x < 10L, -1L)
)))
```

Output (use `set.seed(1L)` before the creation of `my_data` to reproduce)

```
# A tibble: 100 x 12
   group day            x     y     z     a     b     c x_rate y_rate z_rate total
   <chr> <date>     <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>  <int>  <dbl>  <dbl> <int>
 1 A     2021-12-12    68    24    57    91    90    98     68  2791.  6628.    68
 2 A     2021-12-13    39    42    88    57    40    38     39  4884. 10233.    39
 3 A     2021-12-14    -1    48    53    52    -1    51      1  5581.  6163.     1
 4 A     2021-12-15    34    76    86    80    -1    -1     34  8837. 10000     34
 5 A     2021-12-16    87    39    50    -1    -1    64     87  4535.  5814.    87
 6 A     2021-12-17    43    24    80    93    25    26     43  2791.  9302.    43
 7 A     2021-12-18    14    53    30    35    95    85     14  6163.  3488.    14
 8 A     2021-12-19    82    92    93    74    20    85     82 10698. 10814.    82
 9 A     2021-12-20    -1    86    -1    70    84    46     59 10000    233.    59
10 A     2021-12-21    51    40    72    60    -1    -1     51  4651.  8372.    51
# ... with 90 more rows
```

Compare it with the output of

```
my_data %>% mutate(across(
  where(is.numeric) & !contains(c("rate", "total")), 
  ~`[<-`(.x, .x > 0L & .x < 10L, -1L)
))
```

Output without random assignment

```
# A tibble: 100 x 12
   group day            x     y     z     a     b     c x_rate y_rate z_rate total
   <chr> <date>     <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>  <int>  <dbl>  <dbl> <int>
 1 A     2021-12-12    68    24    57    91    90    98     68  2791.  6628.    68
 2 A     2021-12-13    39    42    88    57    40    38     39  4884. 10233.    39
 3 A     2021-12-14    -1    48    53    52    66    51      1  5581.  6163.     1
 4 A     2021-12-15    34    76    86    80    41    -1     34  8837. 10000     34
 5 A     2021-12-16    87    39    50    34    -1    64     87  4535.  5814.    87
 6 A     2021-12-17    43    24    80    93    25    26     43  2791.  9302.    43
 7 A     2021-12-18    14    53    30    35    95    85     14  6163.  3488.    14
 8 A     2021-12-19    82    92    93    74    20    85     82 10698. 10814.    82
 9 A     2021-12-20    59    86    -1    70    84    46     59 10000    233.    59
10 A     2021-12-21    51    40    72    60    -1    55     51  4651.  8372.    51
# ... with 90 more rows
```